# Value always null

Tags: java, arraylist, null

I wrote this code which is apparently right. The problem is that the variable **temp** is always null. On the first cycle the program should enters in the second statement, but this does not happens. Why?

```
ArrayList<Pair<Float, Float>> tmp = new ArrayList<>();    
for (int i=0; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; i++) {
        Float temp = null;
        if (line.equals("----")) {
            i = 0;
            points.add(tmp);
            tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        } else if (i%2 == 0) {
            temp = Float.parseFloat(line);
        } else {
            tmp.add(new Pair<Float, Float>(temp, Float.parseFloat(line)));
            System.out.println("LINE: "+tmp.get(0).first);
        }
    }
```

PS: even the IDE says that the values **temp** will be always null

Comment: because it's uninitialized when the line is not equal `-----`

Comment: I initialized it as well Float temp = new Float(1.0); instead of null but it also doesn't works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare `Float temp = null;` inside your `for` loop. So it will always be set to `null` when an iteration of your loop starts. Even if you hit the second statement, `temp` will get a value but then is immediately discarded and created anew with value `null`.

Try to declare `Float temp = null` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The value is temp is not always null. If you print the value of temp just after parsing it, you will see this.

```
temp = Float.parseFloat(line);
System.out.println("temp: " + temp);
```

If you intend to use the value of temp from one iteration during the next iteration, it would be wise of you not to set the variable to null every time.